# "Unsupported image object", using Tesseract

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, python-tesseract

I am building a character identifier from an image using Tesseract and Python.

This is my code:

```py
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract as pyt
     
image_file = 'location'
im = Image.open(image_file)
text = pyt.image_to_string(image_file)
print (text)
```

I am getting the following error while executing this program:

> TypeError: Unsupported image object

Can anyone solve this issue?

Comment: `image_file` is a string. Pass `im` instead.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Tesseract is having a very low accuracy is there any other method to identify characters in an image in python?

Comment: @SriJack Did you try binarizing your image?

Answer (score 3):

First, remember to add the line

```
 pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'
```

where
`C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe` is the location where your tesseract is installed.
You have indicated that the image file is a string, which is ok, but you did not add an extension of the image!
For example,
you would have written
`image_file = 'location.png'`. The extension **jpeg, or any other format your image is holding**.
Then, instead of writing
`text = pyt.image_to_string(image_file)`, write
`text = pyt.image_to_string(img)` because its an image you are parsing and not a string.
The rest of the code is ok.

**Note:** **You may need to specify the exact location of the image; for example 'C:/Users/Dismas/Desktop/opencv-python/image_text.png'**

But if you still get the same problem, you can use the link [How to install tesseract OCR](https://medium.com/@marioruizgonzalez.mx/how-install-tesseract-orc-and-pytesseract-on-windows-68f011ad8b9b). I followed the steps therein as they are.
I had a similar problem like yours, but now I am sorted.
**The image below may be a good source of better understanding**
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfDZX.png)

Answer (score 3):

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract as pyt
     
image_file = 'location'
im = Image.open(image_file)
text = pyt.image_to_string(im)
print (text)
```

You are passing the string but not the image itself. To fix it just change the line `text = pyt.image_to_string(image_file)` to `text = pyt.image_to_string(im)`. It should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am also faced with the same problem. But, I don't want to try to leave this. So,I installed so many types of the tesseract. The new version of tesseract has to download correctly i.e https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki. After installed, Compulsory need to use package installation in command prompt (`pip install pytesseract` or `pip install --user pytesseract`). No need to add the path in environment variable. Just used the tesseract path directly in the code.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'

img=cv2.imread("image file")
img=cv2.resize(img,(600,500))
cv2.imshow("originalimage",img)
text=pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Note: If the above installations are correctly performed. Then the program is executed.**